# Link to Add Item in developer story leads to 404 page

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

I am talking about the developer story page with link https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/2019247.

On the right side, I can see a popup saying **Your job matches are on hold**. In this popup, the last link says **Work experience or education**. When I click on this link, it works fine when I'm in the **Story view**.

When I change my view to **Traditional View**, and click on the same link, it leads to a 404 page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch. The sidebar link was working on the Story view because a redirect was not needed, but on the Traditional View we wanted to both redirect the user to the Story view and open the Add New Item window. The link url has been fixed and you should not see a 404 anymore. This fix will be up with our next prod build.